# Cluster point and epsilon delta question.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

---

### Questions

Let $D=\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb N\}\subseteq\mathbb R$.

(a) Show that $0$ is a cluster point of D

(b) Let $f: x \mapsto1$ where $x\in D$. Show that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 1$.

(c) Let $g: \frac{1}{n} \mapsto k$ where $\frac{1}{n}\in D$ and $k\in\mathbb N_0$ is the largest number such that $2^k | n$. Show that $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)$ does not exist

---

### My answers

(a)

Theorem: Let $D\subseteq\mathbb R$ and let $x\in\mathbb R$. $x$ is a cluster point if and only if $\exists (x_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ such that $x_k\in D\setminus{x}$ for all $k\in\mathbb N$ and $\lim_{k\to\infty}x_k=x$.

Let $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$ where $n\in\mathbb N$ be a sequence. We can define D in terms of $x_n$.

i.e $D=\{x_n\}$. So $x_n\in D$ $\space\forall n\in\mathbb N$.

Proving that $0\notin D$:
Assume $0\in D$ $\Leftrightarrow \space \exists n\in\mathbb N$ such that $\frac{1}{n}=0 \space$ $\Leftrightarrow 1=0$ $\therefore$ Contradiction $\Rightarrow 0\notin D$ $\Rightarrow D\setminus\{0\}=D$

Therefore $x_n\in D\setminus\{0\}$

$\forall \epsilon\gt 0\space$ $\space\exists N_{\epsilon}\in\mathbb N$ where $N_{\epsilon}=\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ : $\forall n\gt N_{\epsilon}\space$ $\Rightarrow |x_n-0|=|\frac{1}{n}-0|=\frac{1}{n}\lt\frac{1}{N_{\epsilon}}=\epsilon$

Hence $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=0$

$\Rightarrow$ By the theorem provided we have shown that $x=0$ is a cluster point.

(b)

Given $\epsilon\gt0$. We can choose any $\delta$ with $0\lt |x-0|\lt\delta$ we get $|f(x)-1|=|1-1|=0\lt\epsilon$

Hence $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=1$

(c)
I have tried for a while now -struggling to see how to tackle this.

---

### Comments

This is a nasty question which was posed to me on my Analysis I course.
Would be great if anyone could check my work, maybe even give alternative proofs for (a) and (b).
And it would be nice if someone could help me with (c) :)

Comment: c) doesn't make any sense.  We know what $g(x)$ equals if $x = \frac 1n$ but we don't have any indication what $g(x)$ is if $x \not \in D$.  Suppose $g(x) = 1$ for all $x \ge 1$.  Then $\lim_{x\to \infty} g(x) = 1$.  ... was that infinity sign supposed to be a $0$?

Comment: Or is it supposed to be $g: n \to k$ . and not $g: \frac 1n \to k$?

Comment: If it $g: n\to k$ not that for any $M$ and any $m\in \mathbb N$ there is an $x = 2^k > M; k > m$ so $g(x) = k > m$ so $g(x)$ is unbounded and $|g(x)-L|< \epsilon$ for *all* $x > M$ is impossible for any $L$.

Comment: If it is $\lim_{x\to 0} g(x)$ notice for any $\delta > 0$ then *all* $n \ge \frac 1\delta$ are such that $| \frac 1n-0| < \delta$ and so all $n=2^k; k \ge \log_2 \frac 1\delta$ are so that $|x-\frac 1{2^k}|< \delta$. But $g(\frac 1{2^k}) = k$ and that is unbounded and $|g(x)-L|<\epsilon$ for all $|x-0|< \delta$ is impossible.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14SwrFoGr2uTgwo3Wukhy86P1KeXoeWWw/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) and (b) are fine. For (c), you have for example that $$g\left(\frac{1}{ 3^k}\right)=0\quad \text{and}\quad g\left(\frac{1}{2\cdot 3^k}\right)=1,$$ for all $k\in\mathbb N$. Therefore, if $$x_k=\frac{1}{3^k }\quad \text{and}\quad y_k=\frac{1}{2\cdot 3^k},$$ then
$$\lim_{k\to \infty } g(x_k)=0<1=\lim_{k\to \infty }g(y_k),$$
and thus, $g$ has no limit in $+\infty $.

Comment: But the question isn't about $\lim_{k\to \infty}g(x_k)$.  It's about $\lim_{x\to \infty} g(x)$.  SO what if you can make a sequence where $x_k \to 0$.  I can make up a sequence where $x_k\to \sqrt \pi$.  Unless we have a sequence where $x_k \to \infty$ we will *not* have $\lim_{k\to\infty}g(x_k) =\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x)$.  And as we have *NO* idea what $g(x)$ is when $x \not \in D$ we have no idea how to describe the existence or non exisitence of the limit.

Comment: We are on $D=\{\frac{1}{n}\mid n\in\mathbb N^*\}$ and the question is about $$\lim_{\substack{x\to \infty \\ x\in D}}g(x)$$ which is equivalent to the existence of $\lim_{n\to \infty }g(\frac{1}{n})$. Well, this is how I understood the exercise (otherwise the question wouldn't have sense) @fleablood

Comment: The question *doesn't* make sense.  And $\lim_{x\to \infty; x\in D}$ doesn't make any sense as $x \in D$ *and* $x\to \infty$ are contradictory statements.  That's like asking $\lim_{x=5; x\to \infty}$ or $\lim_{5\to \infty}$.

Comment: $x\to \infty; x\in D$ can only mean $x \to 1$ because $1 =\max D$.  So $\lim_{x\to \infty; x\in D} g(x) = g(1) = 0$.  Which... *does* exist.  The question, as written, does *not* make sense.

Comment: @fleablood: You are absolutely right... of course ! (I was confused) I wanted to say that I guess that the OP wanted to say that $\lim_{\substack{x\to 0\\ x\in D}}g(x)$ doesn't exist (which make sense and is true). The reason I think that it's at his question (b) he says that $\lim_{x\to \infty }f(x)=1$, but he proved that $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=1$. I think he confused $\lim_{x\to \infty }g(x)$ by either $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)$ or $\lim_{n\to 0}g(1/n)$... Anyway, strictly speaking you are absolutely right, the question has no sense.

Comment: Here is the question, I did not know how to do the curly braces thing to define the functions. I could of made a mistake when rewording the question: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14SwrFoGr2uTgwo3Wukhy86P1KeXoeWWw/view?usp=sharing